# Socket_write not working after mysql_query

Tags: php, android, mysql, sockets

I'm trying to communicate with my android client to php server using socket. All works great because I can send and receive messages correctly. Now, I need to establish server's action in base of what I sent from the client. In particular there are two possibilities, if I send:

1) "Close" -> I'd like to close the socket with the client and communicate this to it.

2) Other data in form "string"-"string"-"string"-"string"-"string" -> the server has to upload this data to a database mysql and communicate success/failure to client via socket. This is the part of my code needed for the question:

```
if (strcmp(trim($input),"Close") == 0) 
            {
                //remove and close the socket
                echo "close";
                socket_write($client_socks[$i] , "communication close");
                socket_close($client_socks[$i]);
                unset($client_socks[$i]);

            }else{

            //input -> user-lat-long-accurancy-timestamp
            $input = trim($input);
            $pieces = explode("-", $input);

            $user = $pieces[0];
            $latitudine = $pieces[1];
            $longitudine = $pieces[2];
            $accurancy = $pieces[3];
            $timestamp = $pieces[4];

            $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `positions` (`unique_id`, `timestamp`, `latitudine`, `longitudine`, `accurancy`) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$timestamp."', '".$latitudine."', '".$longitudine."', '".$accurancy."');";                       

            if ($db->query($sql22)){
                echo "ok";
                socket_write($client_socks[$i] , "Y");
            }else {
                echo "ko";
                socket_write($client_socks[$i] , "N");
            }
}
```

It does not work because i don't receive the message Y/N. This is an example test of what happens:

```
      Client:                                    Server (on terminal)
"test1-test-test-test-test"         ---->                echo "ok" 
       NOTHING                      <----            socket_write -> Y

"test2-test-test-test-test"         ---->                echo "ko" 
       NOTHING                      <----            socket_write -> N

       "Close"                      ---->               echo "close"
 "YNcommunication close"            <----    socket_write ->communication close
```

Note that I receive "YN+communication close" and not only "communication close". What happens?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your Android code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think that i have find the problem! I add "\n" after the message in socket_write